# Macro accident. Can't left click, read below

Tags: macros

I'm using a macro software that came with my mouse, the macro driver is called "VTPC216" and on the macro, you can change the button it presses, how fast, and some other stuff.

My issue is that when I was messing around with the macro, I accidently set the left click input to be a right click input, and now I can't left click.

I've spent 3 hours trying to figure out how I could reverse this, but I need a solution that does NOT involve clicking on links, downloading stuff, or anything that would require me to left click, since I cant do that.

Comment: Until you fix the issue, or remove the macro driver (and then reinstall, perhaps), use the *keyboard* to emulate mouse clicks. The Enter key, for example, amy work in some apps. See https://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Keyboard-to-Click-Instead-of-a-Mouse

Answer (score 0):

In general: Uninstall the macro software, scrub all its folders, then reinstall.

To uninstall:

- Click the Windows key
- Type "Programs and Features" (the first few characters will suffice)
- Use the down-arrow key to position to it and click Enter
- Use the down-arrow key to position to the macro software
- Click Enter as many times as required
- Reboot (a short press on the Power key is enough to shutdown).

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you specific instructions without knowing your OS, but assuming that you're on Windows, it's likely that you'll be able to use your mouse normally while in Safe Mode. Once you're in Safe Mode, uninstalling the macro program will be just the same as uninstalling anything else.